# Android crashes because of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, crash, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner in Android, but I've done all the research I could on this problem and I just can't seem to find a way to solve it... The app worked fine until I decided to add the SharedPreferences in order to update some high scores. Now I can't seem to make it work, it always crashes at the very start (after the splash screen)

In the on Create method, below the setContentView I have the following lines:

```
    highScores = getSharedPreferences("HighScores", 0);
    hs1 = highScores.getInt("HighScore1", 0);
    shs1 = highScores.getString("sHighScore1", "User1");
```

and a couple more, but mostle they are alternate takes on lines 2 and 3 in the prior code. I have declared the highScores as SharedPreferences in the body of the class. The only place in this class where I use the info gathered from the SharedPreferences is in editing a TextView, which uses the following code:

```
    High1.setText(String.format("1. %04d - %s", hs1, shs1));
```

My guess is that I made an error somewhere in the code, but am unable to find it...

Just for additional info, I only use the SharedPreferences in one other class (which should update the high scores at the end of games) and uses a simillar code:

```
    highScores = getSharedPreferences("HighScores", 0);
    hs1 = highScores.getInt("HighScore1", 0);
    shs1 = highScores.getString("sHighScore1", "User1");
```

The code above was for getting previous high scores, while the code below is used for updating:

```
    prefEditor.putInt("HighScore1", hs1);
    prefEditor.putString("sHighScore1", shs1);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

I have declared the SharedPrefs editor as:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = highScores.edit();
```

I would really appreciate any help, as I can't seem to find what I've done wrong, probably it's a small error somewhere, but it's really driving me nuts :P I would give you more of the code, but I can't see any purpose in that, because it doesn't use the SharedPreferences and I'm pretty sure they're the cause of the issue...

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You should include your logcat.

Comment: Post your debug error from the logcat. This will be of great use

Comment: While we really need your logcat to help you further, have you set a breakpoint at the very beginning (onCreate) of your application right before it gets the scores? My guess is that something might be null

Comment: AT all previous 3 commentators: When people ask these kind of questions, I assume they don't even know they have the logcat for their aid... That's why it would be best to explain how to add the logcat view to Eclipse:

@IanZG - Go to Eclipse, Choose Window -> Show View -> LogCat (choose other if you don't see the logcat option). Then you will see the exception' stack trace, assuming it's an uncaught exception. It will lead you to solving it easily.

Comment: I agree with David and coder_For_Life22, the "logcat" is available as an eclipse window (Use Window->ShowView->Other then Android->logcat to show it if it's not already set up) or simply by typing 'adb logcat' in a shell window. The logcat will contain the very _line_ where your program crashed and the reason why it crashed.

Comment: I've been to the logcat and it told me that an uncaught exception 0x4001d800 took place. I was looking around to see if there is anything like it but so far had no luck...

Comment: Also, it seems the problem is occouring on the line where my new method is called, after the highscores.getstring function. The custom method starts with NewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewGame);, not sure what the problem there could be...

Comment: @IanZG in logcat you should clearly see Where the problem is occuring and What the problem is. Locate several contiguous lines of error messages in the log, the first line is an exception name which is the 'why' part. Scroll down in this error log and you'll find references to your own code along with the line where it occurs.